# how to have tags for tags

Tags: python, django

Here's what I'm trying to do. let's say I have a community page sports and I want to display it's related pages to "sports" page. I would like to show "football", "baseball", "basketball" to my "sports" page.

So I thought about using foreignkey relationship. but with what I've tried "football" page displays "sports". In admin, for football page, for the field, related_cat I'm able to choose other categories. I picked "sports" because I want "football" to be part of "sports". but it displays backward. football page shows sports.

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)(Sponsored, null=True, blank=True)

    related_cat = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)




{% if category.related_cat %}

{{category.related_cat}}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: What about {{category.name}} ? that will print "football" if {% if category.related_cat %} equal to "sports"

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, Django has multiple tagging packages (see https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/tagging/ ).

However, for your question:

You might want to use a many to many instead of foreign key, but assuming you want a strict hierarchy, given an object `Football` which has a `related_category` of `Sport`, and another object `Baseball` which also has a `related_category` of `Sport`, you can get the list of all the things which have a `related_category` of `Sport` by doing `Sport.category_set.all()`